# Expected number of $k$-subsets that share at least half their elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given $n$ random $k$-subsets from a universe of $m$ elements, how many pairs of subsets can we expect to share at least half their elements? (Special case that may be easier: let $m=n$)

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the chance that two $k$ subsets share half their elements?  Now use the linearity of expectation.

Comment: @RossMillikan I didn't think that would work because of the birthday paradox. There, the odds of a pair sharing a birthday is 1/365^2 so linearity of expectation would tell you we need 365 pairs, but we know this is not the case...

Comment: No, that is not a problem.  The odds of a single pair is $1/365$.  The number of pairs grows quadratically with the number of pairs, so the expected number of pairs that match does, too.  Don't confuse the number of birthdays needed for at least one match with the expected number of pairs that match.

Comment: Im just saying, linearity is only for indep vars, but here the vars correspinding to "subsets i,j match" arent independent

Comment: No, linearity is much broader than that.  You don't need independence.

Comment: Oh, sweet. Then it's easy